# Using JPA join via one column and return another one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have table with two columns:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "key")
    public String key;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "value")
    public byte[] value;
    ....some more data...
}
```

And I have another table, with some field where I have a reference to the Document table, via key column reference:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Table {
     ...some values and id...
     @Nullable
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Document.class)
     @JoinColumn(name = "some_document_id", referencedColumnName = "key",
             foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "document_id_fk"))
     @Convert(converter = ByteArrayToStringConverter.class)
     public String documentValue; //join documents by key column and return value column
}
```

What I want, is to fetch not the whole `Document` with all fields when joining it from this table, but to fetch only one column named `value`, and then convert it from `byte[]` to `String`.

I understand that I can just call getter from java code, but I am curious if that is possible by Jpa/Hibernate API?

Comment: `@ManyToOne` cannot be placed on a String field, since it is not a relation! Similarly you cannot use `@Convert` on a relation field.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in your repository with `@Query` annotation like below code

```
@Repository
public interface TableRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Serializable>{

       @Query("select d.value from Table t LEFT JOIN t.documentValue d where d.key=:key")
       byte[] findValue(@Param("key") String key);
}
```

This method will return you a byte[] array that you can easily convert in String using 
`String s = new String(byteArray)`